# Generator for Java software documentation other than Javadoc

Tags: java, source-code, documentation-generator

I built a lot of webMethods. Each webMethod has his own logic implementation.

I want to generate documentation, but not using Javadoc.

I'm looking for software that creates a text file (or other format) for each webmethod, that I can further edit to explain my code.

Preferably open source software.

Comment: I have heavily edited your question, you can further [edit] if you want to. For next time: use good tags, **state explicitly what you are looking for**, and write sentences with correct punctuation.

Comment: Thanks @JanDoggen – with your edit, the question starts making sense! Without it, I was completely lost (and just about voting to close it for being uncomprehensible :) // **Goldbones:** Please follow Jan's advice. You might wish to add the `open-source` tag if being open-source is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would fall under your requirement of it not being a javadoc, but [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) works really well.

I believe doxygen can generate into a text file, but it's most common usage is that it generates it into a series of web pages (with comments for each class, method, etc).

It works across a number of different languages as well (so you don't have to use it only for Java).

It is also open-source (in fact, there are instructions on how to get it from [git](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#benotified)).